# How to display this about shader thing？I merged it, and then don't how to operate

Tags: interface

[image]

[image]

How to display this about shader thing？I merged it,and then don't how to operate.

Comment: Do you want to reopen the shader editor by splitting the window again?

Comment: yes,maybe，thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the header, right beside where it says Object Mode, there's a view menu. Go to it and then Area > Horzontal/ Vertical Split a line will appear on your screen take it to where you would like to slpit the window and Click. Now change the editor to Shader Editor from the menu to the left of where it says Object mode in the header.

[image]

Just in case your header is not visible, there must be a small arrow like thing near the top right corner of your workspace. Click on that to  see the header. Hide the sidebar just using N just in case it's overlapping that arrow.